# ActiveModelでValidationのprependが効かない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
class Hoge
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :tags
  validate :tags, prepend: true

  def run
    p @tags ## ""
    p valid? ## true
  end
end
```

このようなクラスがあります。
私としては、tagsが空かどうかチェックしたいと思っています。
そこで`validate :tags, prepend: true`のように記述しました。
そしてvalid?メソッドを使用して、nilがどうかチェックしたいです。
しかしながら、tagsが""であるにも関わらずTrueが返ってきてしまいます。
またtagsにnilを代入してもTrueが返ってきました。

なぜこのような挙動になるのでしょうか？
ご回答いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

モデルのある要素の空・nilチェックは以下のように記載することでチェックできます。

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :tags, presence: true
end
```

上記のように書き換えた上で `valid?` すると `false` が返ってくると思います。

https://railsguides.jp/active_record_validations.html#presence

Comment: validatesだったんですね...修正したら動きました。ご回答ありがとうございました。